# Utopia Slavery Qualifications

Tags: biology, psychology, slavery

Let's start this whole question off by exorcising the negative connotations of the word from our minds.

**Out foul demons, OUT!**

---

Our fictional near-future world has no negative instances of slavery or oppression in its background. Our fictional country does, however, have a long-standing law that separates the population into two distinct classes or roles. For lack of a better or more generic word, we shall call them slaves and owners.

This choosing is done at, or very near, birth (≤1 week of age). This choosing is done by the doctors/specialist staff at the birth location using state-of-the-art technology designed to make better decisions than those made in the past.

**No credence is given to environmental factors such as race, ethnicity, gender, social position, or family!**

The question is thus. Which factors could staff at a fully equipped medical facility use to test someone's predisposition to something akin to an A/B personality (some personality types are infinitely more comfortable receiving orders rather than giving them and vice versa)?

For the near future setting, consider only technology widely expected to be available within the next 10 years. Please note: this doesn't have to be 100% fool-proof, as no system is perfect.

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely there are any qualities you can measure without wandering into blatant eugenicism. Is your world completely devoid of any tragedy or strife? How can your test ignore "social position [and] family" but still with near-assurity mete people into two distinct socioeconomic classes? How can a baby, supposedly genetically predisposed to slavery, later have children that are not genetically predisposed to slavery?

Comment: @RossC This is why the very first thing in this question is a plea to look at this without the negative connotation we give to the word slavery.  The concept isn't to create slavery as we think or imagine it, but instead to divide the populace into one of the two groups in which they 'would be happier'.  This is, in no way, a stable idea and would likely be overthrown eventually.  But, the basic concept still holds, we look at slavery without the traditional "one caste is higher than the other" approach.  We aren't completely removing their humanity like was done for slaves in our history.

Comment: You are testing infants. Aside from their genetics they're classable as either crying a lot or not crying a lot, which I'd be interested to learn whether or not is a reliable predictor of future proficiency in some quality. Therefore, my genetic question still stands: A person who was identified as basically genetically predisposed to slavery would only have children who were genetically predisposed to slavery. Your test, no matter what qualities it measured, would divide the population utterly, with no crossover, in a single generation.

Comment: Supposing an infant's personality type could be determined by arbitrary qualifiers, you would end up with three groups, not two: those with a Type A personality, those with a Type B personality, and those (like me) with a Type AB personality.

Comment: @RossC Genetics don't work like that.  You can very easily and very readily have recessive genes passed down, assuming whatever genes we test aren't both dominant.  If we can have two brown haired people have a blond child, we could have two slaves have an owner child.  Not to mention, pairings of slave/owner would be a not uncommon experience.  Once again, this assumes all we test is genetics (if we even have the gene for this trait mapped), but we have also seen links in research to certain personalities from brain size and development.

Comment: @Frostfyre And, that's a possibility too.  I'm not ruling out this world having a third, unsorted class that is neither.  Or, in those cases the person might be sorted unhappily.  No system is perfect.

Comment: "Let's start this whole question off by exorcising the negative connotations of the word from our minds." – Impossible. "Utopia Slavery" – Self-refuting.

Comment: Lemme elaborate myself. Slavery will ALWAYS have negative connotations and will NEVER be utopian, as long as people want to be free and have the right to be free. Freedom is one basic right of a person.

Comment: You could as well write: "Utopia Murder" and ask people to exorcise all negative connotations of the word "murder" from their minds. These are analogous cases, you ask to consider something "inherently evil" as if it was not evil. You can claim murder needs not be bad, this will not make it any less bad. Same with slavery.

Comment: @gaazkam I really wanted to avoid unnecessary bloat in a question that is not in any way related to happiness or functionality of said system.  The question itself has only one part to it that has nothing to do with the system actually being a good one.  That said, I can tell I'm going to have to edit the question to provide a lot of background so I can stop getting comments that literally have nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, ethics isn't the bloat of slavery questions, it's the meat.

Comment: Essentially, what it sounds like you're saying is your society has a caste system with "leaders" and "followers". Perhaps using those words (instead of "slaves" and "owners") will get you the response you're looking for.

Comment: **To those discussing the morality of slavery:** that topic doesn't actually affect his question one way or the other. It's perfectly answerable while disagreeing that slavery could be moral, or any related details.

Comment: It doesn't need to be genetic; a disease (not Zika, but in some ways similar) could cause mental effects. If the disease isn't directly detectable then the scenario makes sense. That said, it's hard to imagine a non-detectable disease.

Comment: "Brave New World" by Aldus Huxley was written as his vision of utopia (because it would be so much better than the post-WWI England he lived in). It is definitely utopia slavery by brain washing. I'm not saying I would want to live there, just that there's a rather famous instance of this idea.

Comment: Slavery issue aside, there is literally no way to answer this question because it presupposes facts not in evidence: specifically that people are happier leading or following in all contexts, and that happiness is a trait versus a condition. If you assert both those are true we aren't talking about humans anymore, and there is literally no basis to say what factors to look for.

Comment: @SRM: _A Brave New World_ was satire

Comment: (All of the following needs citation, but I'm a long way from my college course work.) It is taught as satire these days, but I've read critiques by his contemporaries. His ideas about tracking children into particular castes by training were taken seriously. Huxley didn't think his system was viable as described but he was proposing out-of-the-box ideas to spur people to think about ways to save British society at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Setting all ethics aside and trying to stay narrowly within question.

Quite honestly I think that such test at such early age and tech level would be effectively doomed.

1) What can be measured? Vague statistical genetic? With simpler issues than personality, combination of different genes and upringing makes any reasonable prediction a nightmare.

2) Testosterone level in boys? (I'd have to look up how good is correlation in later life, never mind) Those with higher would be even more unhappy about being pushed around... just the problem that using them as the owner race (caste?) would be also not so nice idea.

3) Predisposition towards mental problems like ADHD (neuropsychological, so I could theoretically imagine making early test for that) just again you'd end up with people unhappy being on the bottom, and simultaneously those that would not be so desired at the top.

4) At this age it is much too early to try to measure IQ or similar metric. One could imagine picking the brighter ones just to give orders, but you'd fail that with infants.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside all ethical considerations, inequality, and so on in your society's slavery, what could they test to make it work?

They could test biological sex.  That is a) readily apparent at that age, b) testable, c) the closest of *any* factor capable of being tested, that can actually appear to resolve into two divisible categories (given a couple centuries' worth of proof that those who don't fit into one of those two categories can be forced into or out of "their" category, or else killed).

It will also have the benefit of not dividing people by race, gender, ethnicity, social position, or family. (yes, *also* not by gender.  Because sex and gender aren't the same thing, and who cares how they present as long as the population division is static?).  And it will prevent the two populations from diverging, like separating by most any genetic factor will do.

Of course, it is completely and utterly **irrelevant** which population, that is, which sex, is picked for which role, since the dynamic (leader/follower, master/slave) *does not map* onto biological sex or, in fact, anything, anything a population can be divided into two parts by by any reasonably sane division.  But, on the bright side, there are (again) a few centuries worth of historical proof that this kind of socially taught division can be forcibly maintained for *quite some time*.

Alternatively, you can try dividing by any other things testable and divisible at that age - skin color, or hair color (given an arbitrary but *enforced* division point which separates the "A" from the "B", and some rule about dealing with or ignoring third categories or colors).  Possibly even size, or weight - these will be slightly slower to develop into divergent populations.  Again, they have nothing and less than nothing to do with actual suitability for being a master or salve, leader or follower - but honestly culture and expectations and teaching will probably do a decent job of fitting people to their assumed roles than "genetics", so it should end up a self-sustaining prophecy after a while.

The real problem, by the way, is that you're looking for ways to reliably split the population into *two kinds of people*, and keep them in those categories, when really there are about thirty-seven and a quarter kinds of people, and they won't stay put in their categories, either.  That will trip you up long before you get to the "slavery" of one half the population (or, one "class") or the assumption that those two classes must for some reason map onto genetic tests and also somehow work for suitability to be a "master" or "slave".

They could just as easily drop the idea of a genetic test and divide the populations at random, apportion alternating kids born or generations, or kids on alternating months or years, to be "A"s or "B"s, which will give a lot more intermixing of the population and less chance of permanently separating the populations, than any factor found by a genetic test.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the 37.25 kinds of people there are.

Comment: @MarkRipley - So am I :)  Actually, it's just a good round number for estimating "lots, but *messily* so".  Fractions (.25) because some people will sacrifice their person-ness trying to force others to be not-people.  Gives me the heebie-jeebies, and is evil, and doesn't work, but they try.  The rest comes from every universal A vs B type people a) not being universal and b) actually working out A, B, AB, O, and "not AvsB, it's XvsY!"  Subtract some categories overlapping, merging, or parts by being evil, add extra for oddballs *still* not placed, and keep the last spot for "everyone else".

Answer (score 1):

**I was going to post about using birth order. Yet, researching for this answer I became convinced that birth order as personality predictor is at best as good as astrology (ie. if at all, it is by self identification or social preassure/expectations, not by the gravitational effects of remote stars across the skull or the mother's womb). Instead this answer is about Methods that doesn’t work, kind of.**

---

A simplistic approach: birth order.

Decide what proportion of slaves/owners do society needs, and depending what is more needed make firstborns that.

Of course, the problem with that pragmatism is that it doesn't take into account the predisposition of the child.
It is often hypothesized that the first relationships of the baby shape the personality. Firstborns would get more integration with the parents as the time is not split with a second child; on the other hand subsequent children have big brothers! Does this have any effect?

No, [second children are not more agreeable and are not more creative](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/46/14224). Other psychological traits attributed to birth order has been [debunked in the past](http://www.rapidnet.com/~jbeard/bdm/Psychology/birtho.htm).

In fact, many of the effects of birth order seem to be self-reported instead of discovered by objective measurements of the traits. For example the study [The Relationship Between Birth Order and Personality and Career Choices](http://digitalcommons.providence.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1012&context=socialwrk_students) concludes that firstborn are more  responsible, cautious, motivated, driven, shy, and intelligent. It should be noted that the study surveyed students and asked them to report their own personality traits. The paper repeatedly associates firstborns with leadership and aggressiveness, although it associates creativity traits to second children. In fact it could be argued that the reported traits are a reflection of what people expect of them – if particular when the questionnaire is primed with the question of birth order.

---

A more complicated approach: communication skills.

There have been at least [a](https://aeon.co/essays/romanian-orphans-a-human-tragedy-a-scientific-opportunity) [few](http://ideas.time.com/2013/08/06/your-first-grader-is-going-to-be-a-high-school-drop-out/?xid=rss-topstories&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+time%2Ftopstories+%28TIME%3A+Top+Stories%29) [studies](http://www.edweek.org/ew/articles/2013/07/29/37firstgrade.h32.html) suggesting that interaction with other children, time spend reading (and time to start to read) or other language difficulties may be early indicators of school dropout. This prediction could be mapped to slaves and owners by making the slaves the less likely to drop out (and thus the less likely to cause trouble).
Sadly trying to detect communication skills on a baby matches with the [predictors for Autism](http://www.helpguide.org/articles/autism/autism-symptoms-and-early-signs.htm):

> Your baby or toddler doesn't:
>
> 1. Make eye contact, such as looking at you when being fed or smiling when being smiled at
> 2. Respond to his or her name, or to the sound of a familiar voice
> 3. Follow objects visually or follow your gesture when you point things out
> 4. Point or wave goodbye, or use other gestures to communicate
> 5. Make noises to get your attention
> 6. Initiate or respond to cuddling or reach out to be picked up
> 7. Imitate your movements and facial expressions
> 8. Play with other people or share interest and enjoyment

So, you would be selecting on possible autism. Sadly there are some DNA factors for autism, so these tests are not fully isolated from family discrimination. Furthermore it is unknown if there is a correlation between autism and leadership. Will some research suffice in 10 years?

Answer (score 0):

**Hormones, I say, Hormones**

Your goal is [social stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_stratification), which can be determined reliably at birth, while excluding the most reliable metric available at that time -- heredity.  Consider the future human society of Well's **Time Machine**.

Even a test for "resemblance to Genghis Khan's DNA" would favor some families over others.

You need to deal with the issues of how your society rejected heredity, and how they could accept an alternative and arbitrary metric.

So let's try measuring levels of various hormones, which are produced by a complex interaction of genes.  You can't readily predict which baby will get them, but babies with certain hormone profiles end up developing natural aptitude to understand and operate on the complex physical and social environment of your utopia.  Stratification then becomes simple:

- Children without aptitude for comprehension (as indicated by hormones) cannot grasp the complex structures of your utopia, and are thus fated to become its leaders
- Children with the gift of comprehension delighting in revising and increasing the fractal complexity of the future, and are generally happy to pursue the insane objectives of their leaders

You have many functioning precursors of such a system in modern human society -- in the USA, these systems are called **Corporations**.

Comment: You mean like the alcohol baths as used in Brave New World?